# Multiple Domain CNAME on Azure

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname

I was able to point http://test.invoice-authorize.net to billiving.com by applying a CNAME rule. For some reason when I try to do the same with getting http://test.billiving.net to point to billiving.com DNS cannot resolve.

Any ideas how this could be further debugged?

Additional info:
Both domain names have this CNAME: 
NAME=awverify.test
VALUE=awverify.billiving.azurewebsites.net

Also, Azure account is mapped to both subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my awverify CNAME was mapped to the wrong place. You can actually map subdomains to a different website (or should I say "APP" in Azure) by creating the following CNAME:

```
NAME = awverify.subdomain 
VALUE = awverify.your-website.azurewebsites.net
```

Then Azure will allow you to make that assignment under custom domains section.

Comment: Any solution for this yet? If you sorted yourself out Josh then please post the solution for us that need it. It might be helpful to other users on here.. Thank you!